# how to hide browser address bar when page height is fixed and has internal jquery scroll

Tags: android, browser, jquery-mobile

As the title says all, I am developing a web based mobile app (rss reader). It has a jquery mobile list view that scrolls vertically. The page header and footer are fixed.

In my application I'm using html webs stroge of browser. That's why, I'm not using web view for this purpose. I want my app to look native for that I need to hide the address bar of the browser.

I have tried `windows.scroll(0,1)` but this doesn't work for me as I said for the browser my page has no scroll.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take a look at phonegap maybe it matchs your needs. http://phonegap.com/
it wraps your site and make it look like a native app and it shows no adress bar .

**EDIT :**

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
   window.scrollTo(0,0); // reset in case prev not scrolled  
   var nPageH = $(document).height();
   var nViewH = window.outerHeight;
   if (nViewH > nPageH) {
     nViewH -= 250;
     $('BODY').css('height',nViewH + 'px');
   }
  window.scrollTo(0,1);
  }
});
```

Comment: could you explain how? i think phonegap uses webview ..may be im wrong but kindly explain.i want to open my app in browser

Answer (score 0):

ur height of the body needs to be greater than the phones height in px.
so if ur resolution is 400x800, the height of the body tag needs to be greater
than 800, like 850 or so.

in ur document.ready.. put:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```